# Agreement between employee and employer for use of personal equipment

Tags: contracts, personal-property, byod

I'm going to start a position where I have voluntarily offered to use my personal equipment to perform my duties for the company with the understanding that if any damage would occur to my equipment while using it for company business they would either repair or replace the equipment. It is all verbal at this time but I would like to have it in writing as an agreement for both of us to sign.

What important things should I make sure to define in this form?

Comment: If this is valuable equipment, you need to talk to your insurance agent as well.  Your personal property policy probably has an exclusion for using your equipment for work.

Comment: I'd be curious to know how common this kind of agreement is. My employer covers half of the cost of our personal machines, and gives us a 0% loan for the balance (payments are withheld from each paycheck for two years), with the expectation we'll be using them for much of our work for our consulting clients. One thing they recently added was a proviso that our machines be insured/warranteed (e.g. AppleCare) for two years, which is when we become eligible to buy another machine under the same program. I.e., it's on us to care for our stuff.

Comment: @WesleyLong that's only pertinent if you have a personal property policy.

Comment: @BenBarden - Yes, and learning to swim is only pertinent if you're in the water.  Point being?

Comment: You'll have a hard time keeping your personal stuff separate from work stuff. What if there's a security situation and the company requires resetting device to factory defaults? What if you do some personal work in your free time - does the company have a claim to your work? You'd be far better off using your own equipment for your stuff and use work equipment for work (and nothing else other than work).

Comment: @xxbbcc it strikes me that it would be very easy to separate personal from work, by having two separate accounts on the PC. Or even two completely separate OSs.

Comment: @dwizum Sure, that could work. My point was that the laptop is still controlled by the company - even with 2 OS-s, they could initiate a remote reset. I worked at several companies where people who used their personal phones to check corporate mail had to agree to a remote reset without notice by the company "to deal with potential security issues". I just think it's easier not to go there.

Comment: I guess I take for granted that nothing would only exist on a piece of commodity hardware. Between my personal chromebook and android phone, everything is cloud. If anyone were to somehow remotely wipe either of those devices, just log back in and continue as if nothing happened. My Windows PC at work is similar, all content is on a server or in the cloud. A reset would be no problem. If I had a home PC with an OS that was less cloud based, I would just keep important material in the cloud, or on my own storage at home, and access it remotely.

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/questions-that-basically-ask-twp-to-function-as-someones-google-assistant). (IMO [revision #4 by @DavidK](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/131991/4) fixed it, so that discussion is obsolete.)

Answer (score 2):

One thing I cant emphasize enough is: **Make sure you get your agreement in writing.**  Although by law a verbal agreement is just as binding as a written agreement, it becomes **much much harder** to prove and enforce.

Make sure you include all expected scenarios such as breakdowns and maintenance of equipment. Also clear up grey areas such as: "What happens if my equipment is stolen while being used for company work?"

Also make sure the terms of reimbursement are clear for any costs agreed upon. Will you be reimbursed up front or will you have to replace at your own cost and be reimbursed later?

Think long and hard about any possible situation that may arise and make sure to include that in your agreement.